# Parent-Child inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, routed-events

In my MainWindow, I've got a `ListBox` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `Layout` POCO objects:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Layouts}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Also, in the MainWindow, we define the visual representation of a Layout object using a `UserControl` (LayoutUserControl):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Layout}">
   <local:LayoutUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

When we add objects to the Layouts collection, we see new LayoutUserControls populate the ListBox. This is pretty straight forward.

Now, what I'd like to do, is somehow communicate from the MainWindow to the individual LayoutUserControls. Specifically, from the MainWindow, I want to call a single method on each of the LayoutUserControls... If I attempt to iterate through the ListBox's Items collection, all I get is a reference to the Layout objects, not the LayoutUserControls. Since the LayoutUserControls are defined in a DataTemplate, I don't have a named reference to access them...

Is there a WPF construct that supports this type of interaction from parent to child controls? RoutedEvents were my first thought, but they only support child to parent (bubble) communication. Perhaps commands are the way to go?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a method *which you should never use*, it's the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx).

You should, as you noted yourself, set up the communication differently, commands sound reasonable. Expose a command on the `Layout` and bind the `UserControl` to it. Or create an event and make the `UserControl` subscribe to it, then you can raise that.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. I'd like to stay away from 'old school' event registration if possible. I'm fairly confident I can expose a simple ICommand in the LayoutUserControl. How can I bind to it and invoke it from the MainWindow? Any references or examples you can share?

Comment: @JohnRussell: Well, commands are usually ui to data, and what you want is data to ui, so using an old school event would be a lot easier in my opinion. Using commands surely can work too somehow, but i cannot give a nice method right off the bat, but i'll look into it too...

Comment: Ah. Now, I think I see where you are going... Correct me if I am wrong. I can add a method to the Layout object, call it OnRaiseEvent(). It will be invoked from my MainWindow for each of the Layouts in the collection. Inside the Layout object, OnRaiseEvent would raise an event to the LayoutUserControl to perform my task. Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight there is an extension called GetItemsAndContainers as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463522/allowing-item-selection-indicator-in-listbox-to-overlay-all-items-in-silverlight) that does this but I cannot find an equivalent in WPF.

However it may still be possible as described in [How can I access the ListViewItems of a WPF ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92328/how-can-i-access-the-listviewitems-of-a-wpf-listview) by using the VisualTreeHelper to get the LayoutUserControls inside the ListBox.